# how Do i register 81 textviews in android?

Tags: java, android

I am building a sudoku in android ,so how do i register all the textviews 
for e.g :

```
button1=(Button)findViewByid(R.id.btn1)
```

Do i need to write 81 such statements to register every `TextView`

Comment: Please improve your question - it is a bit confusing because you are talking about `TextView`s and yet your code example uses `Button`s? In any case, you should try adding all those `TextView`s/`Button`s and see what happens. Ideally, you should define `OnClickListener` in the layout XML file so that you do not have to do `findViewById(resource-id)`, unless there's a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: Only `TextView`s ?? .. Just out of curiosity, then how are you planning to enter number to the grid??

Comment: Why not start with some easier tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

you can use grid view with an adapter instead of text views

grid item

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="@string/country_name"
        android:textColor="@color/accent_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/color_primary_dark"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter class

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

private List<ItemObject> itemList;
private Context context;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
    return rcv;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.itemList.size();
}



 public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

 public TextView textView;

public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
}

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 }
 }
```

Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private GridLayoutManager lLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle(null);

    Toolbar topToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(topToolBar);
    topToolBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
    topToolBar.setLogoDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.logo_desc));

    List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
    lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 4);

    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

    RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, rowListItem);
    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
}



private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){

    List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("1");
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("2");
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("3");

    return allItems;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add the views in java code when app running.

you can write your textview's xml statement in an xml file alone, and then inflate it.

In this way, you don't need the view id, because you already have its reference.

grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    />
```

MyActivity.java

```
ArrayList<TextView> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
    TextView view = (TextView)LayoutInflater.from(ItemDragAndSwipeUseActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.grid, null);
    list.add(view);
 }
 // then attach these views to the layout with addView()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use IDs for this. You can just create a View (Container) in XML and fill it using a for loop completely without using IDs. You can access them afterwards via their index in the Container.

I hope this helped.